# Azure function powershell, Why azure table storage only has one row inserted?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I tried to insert log into azure table storage, but it seems it can not append rows. Here is my powershell script below:

```
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name

# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
{
    $name = $req_query_name 
}
function LogToAzureTable( $log )
{
    $time = Get-Date -Format O
    $entity = [PSObject]@{
        PartitionKey = $EXECUTION_CONTEXT_INVOCATIONID
        RowKey = "PID($PID): ($time)"
        LogContent = $log
    }
    $entity | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $outputTable
    $outputTable.done
}
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Hello $name"

LogToAzureTable "test log 1"
LogToAzureTable "test log 201"
```

But the "test log 1" has never been inserted. 
Below is the azure table content:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Why azure table storage only has one row inserted?

If you call `outputTable` **multiple times** in the Azure function, **just the last time could be as output to `outputTable`.**

In your case you call the output to `outputtable` twice, so just the **last record** could be insert to azure table.

**If send 2 HTTP requests then there will be 2 "test log 201" records in your azure table.**

If we want to **insert multiple records** with just one HTTP request, we could construct an **entity array** as output.

```
  [PSObject []] $sampleArray = $entity,$entity2 

  $sampleArray |ConvertTo-Json| Out-File $outputTable
```

Demo code:

```
# POST method: $req
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name

# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
{
    $name = $req_query_name 
}
function LogToAzureTable( $log )
{
    $time = Get-Date -Format O
    $entity = [PSObject]@{
        PartitionKey = $EXECUTION_CONTEXT_INVOCATIONID
        RowKey = "PID($PID): ($time)"
        LogContent = $log
    }
     $time = Get-Date -Format O
    $entity2 = [PSObject]@{
       PartitionKey = $EXECUTION_CONTEXT_INVOCATIONID
    RowKey = "PID($PID): ($time)2"
    LogContent = "$log-2"
    }

    [PSObject []] $sampleArray = $entity,$entity2 

     $sampleArray |ConvertTo-Json| Out-File $outputTable

    $outputTable.done
}

Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Hello $name"

LogToAzureTable "Hello $name"
```